# Sed to awk program convert

Tags: html, awk, sed, tags

```
1 h
2~1 H
$ {
    g
    s/<!--([^-]|-[^-]|--+[^->])*-+->|<[^>]*>//g
    s/\&quot;/"/g
    s/\&amp;/\&/g
    s/\&lt;/</g
    s/\&gt;/>/g
    p
}
```

This SED code removes any tags and comments from HTML file, how can I write the same but on AWK?
Help please

Comment: you are parsing an HTML file with `sed` and now you want *us* to do the same in `awk`. What about using a proper parser instead?

Comment: Show input/output, and explain the logic.Also do what @fedorqui said!

Comment: Change all `s///g` commands to `gensub` and `s///` to `gsub`. simply put it between a pair of curly braces and run it. Apply the subs on `$0` and output them.

Comment: maybe some effort first, what do you already test that failed on similare sed action ?

Comment: It's a hint for the OP to make an effort, not an answer.

Comment: @ShellFish gsub is not equivelant to `s///`

Comment: You are right, thanks for pointing that out. -- That should be `sub` and `gsub` as *User112638726* and *Kent* pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

here is an awk one liner, do the same thing as your given sed:

- load the whole file in memory
- to substitution with same logic as you wrote `s/pat/rep/g -> gsub("pat","rep")`

  ```
  awk -v RS="\0" '{gsub("<!--([^-]|-[^-]|--+[^->])*-+->|<[^>]*>","")
      gsub("&quot;","\"") 
      gsub("&amp;","&") 
      gsub("&lt;","<") 
      gsub("&gt;",">")}7' your.html
  ```

I made an example, and test it with your sed and the awk command above:

```
kent$  cat x.html 
<html>

        <!-- foo bar-->
        <something>
        ok, here I am the &lt;text      &gt;
        <!--foo 
         <IamTheTagInComment/>
        -->
        <emptyTag/>

         <foo>bar</foo>
         <hello> Hi &quot; Ladies &amp; Gentleman &quot;</hello>
        </something>
</html>

kent$  sed -nrf x.sed x.html                                             




        ok, here I am the <text >



         bar
          Hi " Ladies & Gentleman "



kent$  awk -v RS="\0" '{gsub("<!--([^-]|-[^-]|--+[^->])*-+->|<[^>]*>","")
        gsub("&quot;","\"") 
        gsub("&amp;","&") 
        gsub("&lt;","<") 
        gsub("&gt;",">")}7' x.html




        ok, here I am the <text >



         bar
          Hi " Ladies &amp; Gentleman "
```

P.S. **The best way to process html is using a parser. E.g. beautifulsoup is very nice and easy to use.**

Comment: @Neo9514 it makes awk load whole file as a "line"

Comment: `gsub("&gt;",">")}7` why seven? @Kent

Comment: @Neo9514 you can write any non-zero number, right index finger is for me easier. so I took 7.